# Should I override string cast or ToString method?

Tags: c#, string, casting, tostring

If I am creating a class which fundamentally contains a string message, but which also includes useful data associated with the string message, is there any reason I should override the ToString() method rather than defining a cast to string to get the object's internal string message?

Example, I have a Message object called msg whose `text == "Hello"` but which also contains information about the source of the text. I want `Console.WriteLine(msg);` to output `"Hello"`. Should I override `ToString()` or define a cast to string?

Comment: I think this is what one would want to do if he wants to represent his object as `String`. So yes, if this is something you would want to use that way there is nothing to be said against it.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear: You can always write your own `String getMessage()` function that builds your string as you need it. But like I said there is nothing to be said against it to override `ToString()` if you have no use for its' original functionality anyway ..

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should override the `ToString` method.

Firstly: `Console.WriteLine` accepts `object` and calls `ToString` method from it.

Secondly: Sometime in the future you may need to create class, derived from the `Message`. Let's look at this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Namespace
{
    class StringCastBase
    {
        public static explicit operator string(StringCastBase o)
        {
            return "string cast base";
        }
    }

    class StringCastDerived : StringCastBase
    {
        public static explicit operator string(StringCastDerived o)
        {
            return "string cast derived";
        }
    }

    class ToStringOverridenBase
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ToString overriden base";
        }
    }

    class ToStringOverridenDerived : ToStringOverridenBase
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ToString overriden derived";
        }
    }

    class Programm
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            StringCastBase scb = new StringCastBase();
            Console.WriteLine((string)scb);

            StringCastBase scd = new StringCastDerived();
            Console.WriteLine((string)scd);

            ToStringOverridenBase tsob = new ToStringOverridenBase();
            Console.WriteLine(tsob);

            ToStringOverridenBase tsod = new ToStringOverridenDerived();
            Console.WriteLine(tsod);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be

> string cast base
>
> string cast base
>
> ToString overriden base
>
> ToString overriden derived

Since the *static* type of `scd` is `StringCastBase`, the `StringCastBase`'s conversion method will be called (even when *dynamic* type is not `StringCastBase`). Using *virtual* method `ToString` solves this problem.

Comment: I wasn't aware that a derived class would function that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best technique would be to have your class implement a read-only property called (for example) 'Text' which provides the main string. You've said that the class contains additional information beyond the message text - so really, getting the text means extracting that data from your class. And that's exactly what a property is for!

As a convenience, I would probably also override ToString() - in order to (a) assist debugging, and (b) ensure that something meaningful is returned if ToString() is called by other methods - such as Console.WriteLine() - as soon has mentioned in his answer.  Bear in mind that the purpose of ToString() is to provide a string representation of the object, so you might consider whether you want ToString() to only return the main text, or whether you want it to give some indication of the other information the object contains too.

I would definitely not use a cast in this situation. It's semantically wrong for what you are doing. A cast implies you are converting the data from one type to another type. But that's not what you are doing - you're looking to extract a particular piece of data (the main text) from the class. Using a cast for that purpose could be confusing to other developers.

Comment: Thanks, that advice will help me use those features more appropriately in the future!